# Why is there no feature for upping your "answer" in the sandbox?

Tags: discussion, sandbox

**I think the Sandbox lacks a feature.** I don't know what you guys do think about it but I came to think that many posts of the Sandbox get "forgotten" really fast. Even if there are activities on it. And because they are "answers" to a "question", there is no possibility of upping with a bounty or something.

Even [tnb](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) people, which are really helpful, can't fully validate what you're doing in the sandbox, since they have things to do too - obviously.

So what do you think is doable? Or what should we do to "up" a post, since updating or working on it does not do the job? I don't want to flood chats or something, that's why I'm asking it more broadly here.

Comment: Most users that are familiar with the sandbox sort the post by *active*, so editing said post effectively bumps it to the top.

Comment: @Dennis And how "far" do you go when you work in the sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

[What if everyone did this?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)

This is the kind of feature which logically cannot work as intended, so there's no point adding it.

Comment: I see what you mean, but is there something else we can do?

Comment: That's a more general question which is a [meta-tag:discussion] rather than a [meta-tag:feature-request] and has been asked very recently.

Answer (score 0):

Editing your post will move it to the top of Active, which is how most users watch the Sandbox. You can make an editing pass to clarify and clean up your challenge, or to ask for more specific bits of feedback. I think works better than a mindless "bump" feature because it encourages the writer to improve the challenge along the way.

Comment: I agree, but what if the challenge lacks only one little change before it goes live? There is nothing OP wants to change?

Comment: @V.Courtois When I'm nearly ready to post a challenge, I've found it helpful to edit the post to ask for feedback on the parts I still have the most doubts about. It seems that sandbox readers will more readily give feedback when it's for a specific issue or decision.

Comment: ah? not my case tho :( maybe i'm just unlucky